# Same EntityId in different contextElement in fiware

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Is it possible to have 2 contextElements with the same entityId but different entityType in OrionCB?

Example:
In the same Orion CB these two elements:

1.**entityId:** 123456, **entityType:** device

2.**entityId:** 123456, **entityType:** conections

Would it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. A given entity is identified by the combination of **both** its ID and type.

Comment: Ok. I understand that but, if a given entity is identified by those both elements, How it is accepted to create entities using ngsi10 convenience operations in which entitis are created with an empty entityType field? Is it  unrecommended to created entities that way?

Comment: Could you ask that question in a separated Q&A post in SOF, please? That's a good practice in general with SOF in order not to mess the answer of a question with the answer of another and keep separated questions isolated. Thanks!